# Azure Function App's ConfigurationManager.AppSettings return nulls

Tags: azure-functions

I have created an app setting name under **Application settings** as circled in red in the following image (myStorageName).
[image]

It does have value. However, whenever I call the following line in my HttpTrigger function, it returns null.

```
accountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myStorageName"];
log.LogInformation(accountName);
```

I tried to include myStorageName under **Manage** but I don't think `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is meant to retrieve function keys and host keys under **Manage**.

[image]

Any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem. "myStorageName" should indeed be stored under **Application Settings**.

```
accountName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable["myStorageName"];
log.LogInformation(accountName);
```

App setting name is not to be confused with [function keys and host keys.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook)

> There are two types of keys:
>
> 1. Host keys: These keys are shared by all functions within the function app. When used as an API key, these allow access to any
>      function within the function app.
> 2. Function keys: These keys apply only to the specific functions under which they are defined. When used as an API key, these only
>      allow access to that function.

Comment: Should 

accountName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable["myStorageName"]; 
read

accountName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myStorageName");